# ipconfig get first mac address

Tags: windows, ipconfig

I am using this cmd command to get all the MAC addresses of the machine:

```
ipconfig /all
```

The problem is that it prints all the information and provides no switch to print just the mac. It also prints information for many network interfaces. I am interested just for the active one - this is presumably the first one. My next attemp was to parse just the physical address:

```
ipconfig /all | findstr "Physical Address"
```

but this also prints Link-local IPv6 Address and IPv4 Address.

What how can I get just the MAC address from `ipconfig`? I'd love to have some grep functionality. Is there a native regex implemented in cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these commands will filter the literal "Physical Address" string:

```
ipconfig /all | find "Physical Address"

ipconfig /all | findstr /c:"Physical Address"
```

Since this could list more than one MAC address and the first one isn't necessarily the "active" one consider using PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -filter "IPEnabled='true'" |select MACAddress                   
MACAddress
----------
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. The result of the above expression contains a row for each Physical address.  What is the window way of getting just the first result? On linux, I'd use `ipconfig /all | findstr /c:"Physical Address" | head -1`.

Comment: Also, since I am only interested in the first mac value, I tried to regex match the mac with: `ipconfig /all | findstr /R ^..-..-..-..-..-..$`. Unfortuntely, this also matches `DHCPv6 Client DUID` which is at least twice as big as the mac, as if the ^ and $  failed to match+ it also includes the `Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :` string in the result